# How can I avoid repeating myself in doxygen comments (unfortunately without member groups)?

Tags: c++, doxygen, dry, doxygen-member-groups

I'm documenting a (C++) library of mine with doxygen comments.

In this library, I have some cases of overloads of the same function, doing the same thing but with different inputs, e.g.

```
void frobincate(char const* s, int x, bool b);
void frobincate(char const* s, float f, double d);
```

I've noticed Doxygen has group begin and end commands,`///@{` and `///@}`, and so I naively write:

```
/// @brief Perform frobnication
/// @param s just some string

///@{

/// @param x a xylophonic calue
/// @param b a bulwark of a value
void frobincate(char const* s, int x, bool b);

/// @param f a fantastic value
/// @param d a dastardly value
void frobincate(char const* s, float f, double d);

///@}
```

However, looking at the doxygen [documentation for this kind of grouping](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/grouping.html#memgroup) and the [generated output sample](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/examples/memgrp/html/class_memgrp___test.html), it seems that the group-level commands I specified do not apply to *any* group members - just to the group-level documentation. And, in fact, I am not interested in drawing special attention to `frobnicate()` - it's simply a function with more than a single possible type combination of input parameters.

Is there a way for me to not-repeat-myself w.r.t. function documentation, on one hand, but have that documentation text be applied to the actual function, on the other? Or must I resort to copy-and-paste?

Comment: My order of preferences: 1) remove group and copy-paste that @param s just some string  2) describe all 3 params (s, x and f) in group header  3) describe all 3 in "same documentation". What you want to do feels confusing and bad to maintain even if it would work with some trick.

Comment: Make `void frobincate(char const* s, int x)` a template like this `template<typename T> void frobincate(const char* s, T x)` ? Then you will even repeat yourself less (probably even at the implementation level) ;) You might need some SFINAE or concepts to reduce the accepted types but it will still be one function

Comment: @PepijnKramer: I only gave this simple case which can be templatized as a minimal example. I can easily give you examples which aren't templatizable. See edit.

Comment: @einpoklum No problem, I know reality can be more complex ;)
And to tease you a bit, I could answer use parameter packs `template<typename... args_t>`.  But the reality is sometimes also that coding and documentation can be repetitive in boring. And yes I guest this is one of those cases where copy-paste is the thing to do.

Comment: Just thinking... maybe copilot can get you started : [Copilot : Your Doxygen Helper / Code Documentation Streamliner](https://medium.com/@md.abir1203/copilot-your-doxygen-helper-code-documentation-streamliner-5eaa15543278)

Comment: @PepijnKramer: auto-generated documentation is not the kind of documentation I need...

Comment: I understand that but it could give you most of the "framework". I am AI skeptical, but use copilot sometimes for making a first suggestion, (in my case code) and then correct the suggestion (it often is wrong, but in the end it often is close and I end up typing less).  But as said just an idea ;)

Comment: For the `\brief` you can use the `\copybrief` for the `\param` such a thing does not (yet) exists.

Comment: @albert: And will it properly resolve overloaded functions?

Comment: @einpoklum you mean for the `\copybrief`? Did you try it? I did a quick test with the current doxygen version (1.10.0) and this looks OK to me.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>(Thanks @albert for pointing this out)</sub>

You can use the [`@copydoc` command](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdcopydoc) to copy the `@brief` and `@details` documentation content from your first documented item to your second and subsequent items. This should work even when you're referring to one variant of several functions of the same name.

If you do this, you can get rid of the grouping.

Unfortunately, this will currently not copy `@param` documentation.